# Объединить условия из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос, в результате которого я получаю две строки(по каждому подзапросу).

```
select ifnull(null,'Russia'),from_sale from (
SELECT order_delivery_data.order_delivery_data_name,
round(sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end)  /
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'delivered' then 1 else 0 end)) as from_sale
FROM order_delivery_data
INNER JOIN `order` ON order_delivery_data.order_id = `order`.order_id


where order_delivery_data.order_delivery_data_name in ('BetaPost','Pony Express')
and order_createdAt >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (7 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY
and order_createdAt <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (0 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY

UNION
select order_delivery_code,
round(sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end)  /
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'delivered' then 1 else 0 end)) as from_sale
FROM order_delivery


INNER JOIN `order` ON order_delivery.order_id = `order`.order_id
and order_createdAt >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (7 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY
and order_createdAt <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (0 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY
AND order_delivery.order_delivery_code = 'courier'
 )X
```

Как избавиться от двух подзапросов и прописать условия в одном запросе? Что-то типа:

```
FROM order_delivery_data,order_delivery 
where order_delivery_data.order_delivery_data_name in ('BetaPost','Pony Express') 
or order_delivery.order_delivery_code = 'courier'
```

Просто сложить результаты двух запросов нельзя, так как данные имеют разный вес

Вот как выглядит запрос в оригинале

```
select ifnull(null,'Россия'),sum(from_sale) as from_sale from (
SELECT order_delivery_data.order_delivery_data_name,
round((sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'delivered' then 1 else 0 end))/
(sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then 1 else 0 end) +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'delivery-approved' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'problem' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'refuse-to-send' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'refuse-to-receive' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'sent' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'send' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'parcel-returned' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'stop' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'parcel-on-a-place' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'delivered' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'injob' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'fake' then 1 else 0 end)) * 100,2) as from_sale
FROM order_delivery_data
INNER JOIN `order` ON order_delivery_data.order_id = `order`.order_id
where order_delivery_data.order_delivery_data_name in ('BetaPost','Pony Express Россия','Доставка Почтой России',
'КСЭ','Москва BetaPro','СДЭК','СПСР')
and order_createdAt >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (7 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY
and order_createdAt <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (0 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY
UNION 
   select`delivery-types`.`delivery-types_name`,
round((sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'delivered' then 1 else 0 end))/
(sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then 1 else 0 end) +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'delivery-approved' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'problem' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'refuse-to-send' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'refuse-to-receive' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'sent' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'send' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'parcel-returned' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'stop' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'parcel-on-a-place' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'delivered' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'injob' then 1 else 0 end)  +
sum(case `order`.order_status when 'fake' then 1 else 0 end)) * 100,2) as from_sale
FROM `delivery-types`

INNER JOIN order_delivery ON `delivery-types`.`delivery-types_code` = order_delivery.order_delivery_code
INNER JOIN `order` ON order_delivery.order_id = `order`.order_id
where order_delivery.order_delivery_code is not null
and order_createdAt >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (7 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY
and order_createdAt <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (0 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY
AND order_delivery.order_delivery_code = 'courier'
 )X
```

Но находить сумму двух значений некорректно `sum(from_sale)`, т.к. не учитывается вес этих значений.

Comment: Вы думаете это возможно просто смотря на ваш запрос ? Нет, это можно сделать (наверняка) только видя реальные данные и зная, какой результат ожидается. Тем более, что ваш запрос потенциально может завершится с ошибкой в результате деления на ноль

Comment: @Mike в `order_delivery_data_name ` и `order_delivery_code` хранятся названия курьеров. Остальные условия одинаковы в подзапросах.

Comment: И плюс к этому ваш текущий запрос выдает просто 1 или 2 строки с некими числами и идентифицировать какое из чисел из какой части запроса не представляется возможным, т.к. union _не гарантирует_ порядка выборки, результат может быть в любом порядке. И результат будет 1 строка в случае если числа совпадут

Comment: И информация о order_delivery_data_name и order_delivery_code мне ни о чем не сказала, так как значения этих двух полей вообще не используются в внешнем запросе, следовательно их можно безболезненно убрать

Comment: но скорее всего вам надо добавить некий group by по такому условию которое выдает 0 или 1 в зависимости от соблюдения дополнительных условий и некое поле по такому же условию в список выборки и в итоговый order by внешнего запроса

Comment: @Mike добавил апдейт в вопрос. Не совсем понятно,как вы предлагаете использовать group by в данном случае?

Comment: в `where` подбираете сразу и те и те записи. т.е. `(order_delivery_data.order_delivery_data_name IN(...) OR order_delivery.order_delivery_code = 'courier')` и добавляете `group by  (order_delivery_data.order_delivery_data_name IN(...) )` так же выводите это же условие в списке выборки и его же добавляете в order by. оно даст для записей которые IN 1 для остальных 0